# Iterator returning error for TreeMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, treemap, sortedmap

I have a TreeMap defined like:

```
final TreeMap<ArrayList<String>,String> mymap = new TreeMap<ArrayList<String>,String>(comparator);
```

When I try to iterate over it like this:

```
Iterator iter = (Iterator) mymap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
    }
```

I am getting error message like **The method hasNext() is undefined for the type ObjToIntMap.Iterator** on the 2nd line and **Multiple markers at this line
    - Map.Entry is a raw type. References to generic type Map.Entry should be 
     parameterized** on the 3rd line.

What is the source of this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: dont you think TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> would be better ? String being a key

Comment: 1. I can't reproduce the error with the code you have posted 2. It is good practice to use generics everywhere: `Iterator<Map.Entry<ArrayList<String>, String>> iter = mymap.entrySet().iterator();` 3. Doing 2 might help you understand what the error is.

Comment: @Deepak, yeah I know it looks odd, but I need to do this to have a custom comparator function..

Comment: @assylias, when I do 2, I am getting an error message like **The type ObjToIntMap.Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Map.Entry<ArrayList<String>,String>>**.

Comment: By curiosity, why not use a foreach loop on the `.entrySet()` of the map?

Comment: @Cupidvogel this means you are using the wrong iterator class. See my answer.

Comment: @fge, No particular reason, just wanna know where am I erring..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you imported the wrong `Iterator` class? Are you sure you have imported `java.util.Iterator` and no other class from an other package that is also named `Iterator`?

If you imported the correct `Iterator` class you can remove the typecast and add the generic type to the iterator:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<ArrayList<String>, String>> iter = mymap.entrySet().iterator()
```

Comment: Yeah yeah, dunno where from another `iterator` class was imported! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Another problem, when I am trying to access the 1st element in the key arraylist by `entry.getKey().get(0)`, I am getting error message **The method get(int) is undefined for the type Object**. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You are aware that you cannot alter a key once it is added and it's concrete type shouldn't matter(or be used ideally)

```
final Map<List<String>,String> mymap = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
for (Map.Entry<List<String>, String> entry : mymap.entrySet()) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    Iterator<Entry<ArrayList<String>, String>> iter = mymap.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Entry<ArrayList<String>, String> entry = iter.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-each loop to iterate through a map:

```
for(Map.Entry<List<String>,String> entry : mymap.entrySet()) {
    List<String> key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();

    // Do something useful with the key and value
}
```

Or you can just loop over the keys using `mymap.keySet()` or the values `mymap.calues()`.